# Query about using CoM frames to find total energy available to excite target nucleus

Tags: classical-mechanics, particle-physics, conservation-laws

If we have a particle of mass $m_1$ fired with a velocity $v_1$, at a stationary mass, $m_2$. Why are the following statements true?

[image]

In the LAB frame, there is a net momentum, which
must be conserved. All KE is not available to be transferred to particle 2.
And if in the CoM frame, there is no net momentum and so all KE in CoM frame is available to be transferred to particle 2.

I understand how the difference in momentum comes about, I just can't seem to show that if there is no net momentum, all of the initial KE can be transferred to particle 2. Why is this not possible when there is some net momentum required to be conserved?

Context:

This is taken from my particles and nuclei lecture notes. The above case is used to show that it is energetically more favourable to fire a light nuclei at a heavier one to induce fission.

Part of the derivation involved viewing the resulting collision in the CoM frame and looking at the energy of each particle and claiming that the total energy of the system in the CoM frame is the energy which can be used to excite the target nuclei , $m_2$. I do not see why this is the case, and hence the above question.

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to discuss the difference in available Mandelstam variable $s$ in fixed-target and collider contexts, so it is a thing with real and practical consequences. But as presented here the terminology is inconsistent and the conceptual model feels incoherent. There are already a few question on the site that deal with these issues. You could try searching for the combination of "collider" and "fixed target".

Comment: @dmckee I have edited my question to provide more context, if you know of any related questions could you kindly link them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...Why is this not possible when there is some net momentum required to be conserved?

If any system has a non-zero magnitude of initial momentum, then the system must end up having the sam non-zero magnitude of momentum at any moment as long as the system's momentum is conserved. So, now if the magnitude of the system's momentum is not zero, then clearly at least one component of the system must have a non-zero velocity. This implies that the system has some kinetic energy. Like, this is similar to saying that **non-zero momentum implies non-zero kinetic energy**(the proof is trivial).

So you see that the system has a final non-zero kinetic energy. That means that it has not lost all of its initial kinetic energy. That means, not all of the initial energy(which is completely in the form of kinetic energy) can be transferred to excite the nucleus 2.

**Food for thought :-** Does non-zero kinetic energy imply non-zero momentum? Try to take some cases and figure this out.

*Spoiler :-* You have yourself written a counter-example for the above question(Food for thought) in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no external forces acting on the two masses, then momentum (and angular momentum) will be conserved in any frame of reference. (In the center of mass frame the total momentum will be zero before and after.)  If you know that the collision is elastic, then mechanical energy is also conserved, otherwise energy can be lost to heat.  (In an elastic collision in the center of mass system, each mass will have the same speed before and after the collision (but the directions may change).

Comment: This does not answer my question. If a collision is elastic, the energy is conserved in all reference frames. I have edited my answer to provide more detail as to what I am confused about.

Comment: Sorry, I did not fully read and understand the question.    If the masses stick together, then in the laboratory frame any remaining kinetic energy will be associated with the motion of the center of mass.  This can be minimized if the mass of the projectile is small compared with that of the target.

Comment: In the laboratory frame, using conservation of momentum and energy (with some used to excite the nucleus) the required kinetic energy for the incoming particle is K.E. = U(m+M)/M where U is the excitation energy and m is the incoming mass.  To answer your question: In the CoM system, the initial and final momenta must be zero.  If the two masses stick together, then the final single mass must be at rest.  The total initial energy may go into the excitation.

Comment: Note:  The kinetic energy of an object depends on your choice of a reference frame.